# Configuration possible to disable function lock

Tags: keyboard, 22.04, keyboard-layout

I have a new notebook and although I am very happy with it, I very often accidentally enable/disable fn lock which drives me nuts. Is there a way I can configure/disable fn lock combination (Shift + fn) like by using xmodmap or something?

EDIT: `xev` does not output anything for the key combination in question.

Comment: No there isn't a way. Fn lock is handled   completely within the keyboard, like Caps lock. The computer is never notified of Fn lock.